# Pass Data from one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two pages (page1.jsp and page2.jsp). in page1.jsp i retrieve some values from database and display hyperlinks corresponding to those values. Now what i want is when i click any of those hyperlinks, in page2.jsp i should display other fields coressponding to the vlaue from the database. So what i essentially want is when a link is clicked the associated value must be passed to page2.jsp where i query the database to retrieve other fields.

Answer (score 1):

> when a link is clicked the associated value must be passed to page2.jsp where i query the database to retrieve other fields

So, you want to **preprocess** the HTTP request before displaying the JSP? For that you need a servlet.

Assuming that the links in `page1.jsp` are displayed like follows:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${ids}" var="id">
        <li><a href="page2?id=${id}">View data for ID ${id}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Then you will be able to preprocess the HTTP request in the `doGet()` method of a `HttpServlet` which is listening on an `<url-pattern>` of `/page2`:

```
Long id = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
Data data = dataDAO.find(id);
request.setAttribute("data", data); // Will be available as ${data} in JSP.
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page2.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In `page2.jsp` you will be able to access the `data` as follows:

```
<p>The data for ID ${param.id} is:</p>
<p>Field 1: ${data.field1}</p>
<p>Field 2: ${data.field2}</p>
```

#### See also:

- [All about Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World example and useful links

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by either passing GET or POST variables to the corresponding jsp page and reading them using jsp:

using GET method:

```
<a href="page2.jsp?datatobesend=value">link</a>
```

If you want to do this dynamically you will have to add to that on click using javascript:

GET using jQuery js library:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mylink').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'?datatobesend=value');
 });
});
</script>
<a href="page2.jsp" id="mylink">link</a>
```

There are many ways to use GET/POST to send data from one page to another, this is just as quick as I could write one up :-)  Using form submissions are another place you should look into if this way doesn't work out for you.

Comment: hi, actually i store the values retrieved from database in variable. and i would like pass this as a variable itself to another jsp page

Comment: can you just out put that variable at the end of the link as I did in my first example?

Answer (score 0):

lIf you are talking about a variable that can't be serialized as a string and passed as an http parameter, as suggested, then you need to store the variable within the session.

```
--page1.asp
<?
session.setAttribute( "val", record );
?>


--page2.asp

<?
//Cast this to your type
Object record = session.getAttribute("val");

// Clean it up now that you're done
session.removeAttribute( "val" )
?>
```