# javascript and jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

when i try to access a jsp variable in javascript i always get it as null. why is this so? how do i get actual jsp variable value in javascript. here is my code

```
<%! String oldpassword; %>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect()
        {
        var oldpassword_actual="<%= oldpassword %>";
        var oldpassword_entered=document.form.oldpassword.value;
        var newpassword=document.form.newpassword.value;
        var reenterpassword=document.form.confirmpassword.value;

        alert(oldpassword_actual);
        alert(oldpassword_entered);
        alert(newpassword);
        alert(reenterpassword);
        return false;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
    <form name="form" action="" method="post">
            Enter old password<input type="password" name="oldpassword"></br></br>
            Enter new password<input type="password" name="newpassword"></br></br>
            Reenter new password<input type="password" name="confirmpassword"></br></br>
        <%
        oldpassword=(String)session.getAttribute("Password");
        %>
            <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" onclick="return redirect()"> 
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

when the alert box pops up..it gives a null value for the jsp variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the JSP variable is been printed as JavaScript variable *before* the form is submitted.

Short explanation: JSP runs at webserver, produces HTML/CSS/JS, webserver sends it to webbrowser, HTML/CSS/JS runs at webbrowser. Long explanation: [communication between Java/JSP and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html).

How to solve this: replace JavaScript by a [Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). JavaScript isn't the right tool for the job of request processing.

Comment: Learn servlets. Click the link in the last paragraph. This has been recommended to you [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412758/pass-data-from-one-jsp-page-to-another-jsp-page). You're currently crawling on the wrong track in an attempt to run before you can walk. Don't do that, you would end up nowhere. Learn the basic concepts of web development and JSP/Servlet properly.

Comment: ya i do know i am crawling on the wrong track but i have a very short time to submit my project to my professor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move:

```
    <%
    oldpassword=(String)session.getAttribute("Password");
    %>
```

To the top of your code (or somewhere above the line: var oldpassword_actual="<%= oldpassword %>";)